# Changes in java binary class format specifications

Tags: jvm, bytecode

Is there anywhere in the Internet the list of things that were changed in jvm bytecode (or class format) specifications over the years?

For example I know that there was a bunch of new attributes added to classes since class file versions 49.0 and 51.0. And also that `ldc*` instructions supports more arguments since 49.0. Is there a complete list of such changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the JVM specifications for different versions.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any place that cleanly lays out all the differences, but you can get an idea by looking around [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). For versions 1.5 and 1.6, the changes are highlighted in red.

I think the main things added were optional attributes to support new features in the Java language - anotations, enums, inner classes, generics, and the like. 51.0 also addes all the invokedynamic related stuff. 50.0 adds the StackMapTable which was made mandatory in 51.0. Also, 50.0 removed the jsr/ret instructions.

IIRC `ldc` can load Class constants starting in 50.0 and MethodType constants starting in 51.0